# What's the question to this and what is its answer?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I do not want to verbally tell you what the question is.
However I do want to non-verbally tell you, by showing you some simpler problems in the spoiler below.

Please do not spoil the "question" of these problems if you have encountered similar problems before.

This is my original work.

I would like to know what your first thoughts and ideas are for what the question to these problems is. I am also interested in what you think the answer to the non-spoiler problem is, as its solution is not precise.

If you would like a challenge, then do not look at the spoiler below.

> [image][image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The common 'question' that all of the problems have is:

> What rule do all the squares on the left follow that the squares on the right do not?

The answers to the three problems marked in the spoiler are thus:

> Rule: Each square has exactly one dot.

> Rule: Each pair of lines are parallel to each other.

> Rule: Each shape has left-right symmetry.

And the answer to the overall question is then:

> Rule: Each square shows a 'correct answer' to a mini-puzzles. Those puzzles, from left to right, then up to down, are: 
>
>  
>  1. categorizing the black shape
>  2. multiplying the number of dots by 2 
>  3. categorizing the dots by color
>  4. folding the displayed 2-D shape
>  5. rotating 180 degrees and inverting the color to find the correct symbol
>  6. matching the key at the top to the given symbols

Comment: Have you seen problems like these before @Nahmid?

Comment: @JAGO I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongard_problem) is what they are usually called. In fact, PSE has a [tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bongard) for these kinds of problems

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. I know these problems already and I'm aware the tag exists, however I am interested in testing how people react to them without any explanation.

Comment: @JAGO No, but I figured it out through the spoiler hints!